# What are all the potential outcomes at the ending screen?

Tags: oxenfree

At the end of Oxenfree, you hear the results of your decisions and the division of the results of said decisions between all players in the form of pie charts, such as this one:

> [image]

Unfortunately, you can only see what you chose. What are all the potential outcomes?

Comment: Here's a Reddit thread that attempts to answer this: https://www.reddit.com/r/OXENFREE/comments/41u0aq/spoilers_all_ending_variations/ Also this post here: http://www.ign.com/wikis/oxenfree/Endings

Answer (score 1):

Here is every single outcome I'm aware of:

- Bonding or not bonding with Jonas
- Bringing Ren and Nona together as a couple or not
- Forgiving, sacrificing or hating Clarissa
- Bringing Michael back or not(this affects the Jonas story because if you do  - decide to bring Michael back, it makes  Jonas Ren's friend, although you can  - still decide to bond with him or not

There are also some other outcomes, like getting Jonas and Nona to bond, although not romantically, and I have no idea how to that.

There's also getting all of your friends to hate you, but do you really want to do that?

That's every outcome I'm aware of.  In my personal opinion, the best ending is getting Ren and Nona to date, getting Clarissa to forgive you, bonding with Jonas, and not bringing Michael back.

Answer (score -3):

- Sacrificing Clarissa
- Being Distant, Close, etc to Jonas
- Bringing back Michael
- Letting Michael Die

Comment: Only one of your points actually mentioned multiple options. I know for a fact Clarissa had at least 5 outcomes associated with her. If OP had chosen the same choices as the ones you've listed, they would get nothing from this answer.